# Is there some way to detect if a connected socket is using telnet?

Tags: c#, sockets, telnet

I'd like to know if a connected socket is using telnet or a different protocol.

What is required to know this? Do I need to inspect network traffic?

Also is there a third party library that might help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. The first hint that a user is connecting to a "Telnet" socket is the port number, the official port is 23, however the server could be listening on any port.

The biggest issue with detecting Telnet is that there isn't always a strict "Telnet" protocol in use (although one exists) because the server can choose not to implement it and simply talk straight vanilla ASCII. You're essentially dealing with plain ASCII characters and (optional) control characters travelling over a plain old TCP connection. There are some big hints that most telnet servers give out that give them away though, but you'll need to inspect the traffic to be sure.

The things to look for in the network traffic are:

1. The traffic is mostly ASCII characters, usually with English words or linux program names in the mix.
2. Control characters. These are not guaranteed to be implemented by all Telnet servers (or the terminal sitting behind it), but almost always are. Specifically look for [CSI control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes), which do things like change terminal size, colour, and cursor position.
3. The smoking gun, [Telnet Negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854). Usually the Telnet server sends these commands upon connection, and the client can respond with information as well. It handles some other functions such as terminal resizing and character sets as well, but again, not all servers implement this. From this info, you can usually scrape what client application the client is using (eg Putty).

Detecting any of these things in a TCP connection is a pretty big indication that a Telnet session is taking place.

Comment: Would SMTP and a Telnet session look the same ?  Is Telnet so pimitive that many established protocols and services would look like telnet? .

Comment: Although SMTP contains plaintext, it lacks an abundance of CSI control codes and any Telnet negotiation messages. There could be false positives detected in emails that contain certain attachment encodings however.

You could also look for SMTP and other plaintext protocols and explicitly filter them out, but at the end of the day it could really just be a raw TCP connection. Anything could look like anything.